# Не работает запуск через cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

OS Ubuntu 16.04
Нужно запустить leafpad с помощью cron в нечетную минуту текущего часа по нечетным дням.
Использую для 18 ноября 04 часа.

```
1-59/2 4 */2 1-12 0-7 DISPLAY=:0 leafpad
1-59/2 4 2-31/2 1-12 0-7 DISPLAY=:0 leafpad
```

Но эти команды не работают как для 18 числа, так и для 19. Следующая команда работает(открывает leafpad) как для 18, так и для 19.

```
1-59/2 4 1-31/2 1-12 0-7 DISPLAY=:0 leafpad
```

Объясните пожалуйста мою ошибку?

Comment: раз не работает шаг для числа месяца, вставьте явное перечисление: `1,3,...`. чтоб вручную не набирать, можно сгенерировать строки: `$ seq -s , 1 2 31; seq -s , 2 2 31`. // и, да, `1-12` и `0-7` — излишние перечисления. их оба можно заменить звёздочками.

Answer (score 1):

судя по содержанию [вот этого ответа](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16094/110559), чётные числа месяца надо указывать так:

```
2-30/2
```

а нечётные так:

```
1-31/2
```

---

и, да, чтобы указать «любой месяц», не нужно писать `1-12`, достаточно `*`. аналогично и для указания «любого дня недели»: вместо `0-7` тоже достаточно `*`.

Comment: Я вам больше скажу, для дня недели `*` и `0-7` - это не одно и то же. Согласно документации, если оба поля "день месяца" и "день недели" указаны (т.е. отличаются от `*`), то команда запустится, когда выполняется _хотя бы_ одно из условий. Таким образом, если указать день недели как `0-7`, то команда будет запускаться каждый день, независимо от дня месяца.